# Join Tables CakePHP export as CSV

Tags: php, cakephp, csv, export-to-csv

In Cakephp documents I found the following article how to create CSV export.
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/jeroendenhaan/2010/04/23/exporting-data-to-csv-the-cakephp-way

My problem is with a joined table. In the following code

```
<?php
// File: /app/views/orders/csv/export.ctp

// Loop through the data array
foreach ($data as $row)
{
    // Loop through every value in a row
    foreach ($row['Order'] as &$value)
    {
        // Apply opening and closing text delimiters to every value
        $value = "\"".$value."\"";
    }
    // Echo all values in a row comma separated
    echo implode(",",$row['Order'])."\n";
}
?>
```

In this case when I have lets say a join table of Orders and Users the second foreach will fail. Is there a generic way to go through all the joins? as I might have 3 tables joined.

Comment: If you look at the structure of the first `$row` - you should be able to answer your own question (though `the second foreach will fail` - no it wouldn't. It'd just ignore the user data). Alternatively there's no example in the question, nor expected output - the example is only appropriate/clear for a flat data dump.

Comment: Thanks I think I found my initial problem that in my code I didn't have the `$row['Order']`, but just `$row` so if I loop through `$row['User']` it'll solve my issue.

Comment: A bit of a tangent, but I'd recommend `https://github.com/ProLoser/CakePHP-CSV`

It's worked well for my Cake projects. :)

Comment: Thanks @Chronix3 I'll give the plugin a go, though its documentation isn't the best. they should have instructions like it's the first plugin you use, but I managed.